# UDP connection between client and server not loading on my Mac

Tags: c, macos

i use a Mac from programming in C through Xcode. The version is macOS Mojave 10.14.
The code i'm using has a client who asks for time and a server who replies giving him the current time printed through a UDP connection.
I use client 127.0.0.1 to launch client.
The code works perfectly on linux, but on Mac it just starts loading and never stop.

These are the codes.

UDP Client
https://github.com/lufth/UDPClientServer/blob/master/clientUDP

UDP Server
https://github.com/lufth/UDPClientServer/blob/master/serverUDP

Comment: One issue I've had is that if the machine is not connected to any network at all, UDP code often doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS, there are several security features in place which is different from a linux machine. Maybe you could check to ensure if your program is not hindered by these 2 security features

- Code Signing
- Sandbox

For the sandbox, you may check if your UDP client / server executable is attempting to read/write to a location which is outside its allowed locations.

Alternatively, you may also try to run your server and client as root too

```
sudo java client.java 1111
```

Comment: I tried with sudo and it doesn't work, how can I check Code Signing and Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

The *address_len* parameter to `recvfrom` is an in/out parameter, but in your server you are passing a pointer to an uninitialized variable, `len`.

(Also, it is probably a good idea to give your C source files names ending in `.c`.)

Comment: they of course end in .c, these are not the files I'm using I just have copy/paste the line code. Sorry I should've uploaded the direct files. The len you are referring to is needed cause is where the dress len(so the client's address len) is situated

Comment: My point is: you need to initialize `len`to the size of the receiving struct *before* calling `recvfrom`. `recvfrom` will then change it to the number of bytes actually stored.

Comment: ty, i solved it this way. The point was that on linux the variable was initialized by itself after the first compilation, while on macOS it doesn't.